# Javascript function does nothing when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am working on a website containing a user panel. I want to do a list of buttons you can press. When you'd press a button, it would display html on the other box next to it. The problem is when I press the button that is linked to the js function, it does nothing. Do I have to do a loop that checks every time if the variable is at the requested number? Anyways, here is the code (there's php in it but it doesn't cause any problems):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minecraft Server Panel v1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/inputs.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="background: url('background.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="panel">
       <div class="info" style="text-align: center;">Welcome back,  <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>! <a href="php/logout.php" class="link">Logout</a></div><br />
        <?php
          $on = false;
          if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1){
          ?>
          <div class="separator"></div><br />
          <div class="gray-zone" style="float: left;">
           <a href="javascript: select(1);">Edit Config</a>
          </div>
          <div class="gray-zone overflow" style="float: right; margin-right: 100px; text-align: left;">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  function select(var number){
                    if(number == 1){ document.write('<p class="text" style="font-size: 15px;">Op permission level: </p><select class="selector" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -17px;"><option value="" selected="selected">Select a level...</option>    <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');     }
                  } 
                </script>
          </div>
          <?php
          } else {
            header('Location: other/msgbox_disconnected.html');
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at jQuery if you are playing with javascript, makes life a lot easier ;) http://jquery.com/

Comment: What button? By the way, does the `header` in php really work when the headers has already been sent?

Comment: You're using `document.write()` in your "click" handler, so even if the handler were being run it still wouldn't work. Once the page is loaded, subsequent calls to `document.write()` will obliterate everything.

Comment: `<?php session_start();`  must be called before outputing anything to the browser. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php , `header()` too. Your code couldn't works

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems. I suggest that you find a book or something online and learn the basics of html, css, javascript and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove var in the function parameters:

```
function select(number){
   if(number == 1){ document.write('<p class="te….select>');     }
}
```

Comment: it works but it removes the page and just displays the document.write

Comment: Yep, I would propose you put a div somewhere in the page and replace the content of the div with the html. Something like document.getElementById('id-of-the-div').innerHTML = 'some HTML';

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<a onclick="select(1);">Edit Config</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining parameters in a Javascript function, you do not need to add var in front of your variables.

The correct code is:

```
function select(number){
     if(number == 1){ document.write('<p class="text" style="font-size: 15px;">Op permission level: </p><select class="selector" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -17px;"><option value="" selected="selected">Select a level...</option>    <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');     }
}
```

Also you need to check when you use the "header" function in PHP. If you are not logged in you will get an error informing you headers have already been sent. You must make sure you do any header changes before you do any output. And don't forget to exit or the script will run past a header redirect:

```
header('Location: other/msgbox_disconnected.html');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you cannot declare a JS function using var you can change it to function `select(number)` I have modified your code that is working. Also you need to have defined the JS function before call it in this case

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minecraft Server Panel v1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/inputs.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
                  function selectTestAlert(number)
                  {
                  if(number ==1)
                    {
                     alert("Test"); 
                     }  
                  } 

                   function select(number){
                    if(number == 1)
                    { 
                       document.write('<p class="text" style="font-size: 15px;">Op permission level: </p><select class="selector" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -17px;"><option value="" selected="selected">Select a level...</option>    <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');     
                    }
                  } 
                </script>
</head>
<body style="background: url('background.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">

    <div class="page">
      <div class="panel">
       <div class="info" style="text-align: center;">Welcome back,  <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>! <a href="php/logout.php" class="link">Logout</a></div><br />
        <?php
          $on = false;
          if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1){
          ?>
          <div class="separator"></div><br />
          <div class="gray-zone" style="float: left;">
           <a href="javascript: select(1);">Edit Config</a>
          </div>
          <div class="gray-zone overflow" style="float: right; margin-right: 100px; text-align: left;">
                function select(number){
                    if(number == 1){ document.write('<p class="text" style="font-size: 15px;">Op permission level: </p><select class="selector" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -17px;"><option value="" selected="selected">Select a level...</option>    <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');     }
                  } 
          </div>
          <?php
          } else {
            header('Location: other/msgbox_disconnected.html');
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```